# Confused with UPDATE query. How to convert select to update with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

*I have seen very similar if not same questions on here but my trials of trying to convert following query into an UPDATE statement failed.*

```
SELECT table.* FROM table JOIN (
  SELECT   column, COUNT(*) AS rank
  FROM     table
  GROUP BY column
) AS t USING (column) WHERE t.rank = 1
ORDER BY t.rank DESC
```

I want to update column of all results selected using the query above.

How can I convert this into an update statement?

Thank you.

Comment: The [MySQL UPDATE syntax supports joins...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)  That said, it's not clear what you're updating.

Comment: In particular, are you trying up update the rank value from the subquery or setting something to a constant where rank = 1?

Comment: Hello, somebody messed with my question with an edit. As I stated in my original Q, here, I want to update the "column" which is any column of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update table
set column = 'somevalue'
where id in
(select id from (

SELECT table.* FROM table JOIN (
  SELECT   column, COUNT(*) AS rank
  FROM     table
  GROUP BY column
) AS t USING (column) WHERE t.rank = 1) x)
```

Comment: @Sudhakar that's not what I understand from the question... *I want to update a **column** of all results ...*

Comment: Icarus, I am running the query now. It is taking quite a while though, hope it works, thank you!

Comment: @Phil I hope it works too and most than anything, I hope you have a backup of your database :P

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure but i think it's something like

```
update tblname set columname = value where tblname.columncompare = (select statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value)
SELECT table.id, table.value
FROM table
JOIN (
  SELECT   column, COUNT(*) AS rank
  FROM     table
  GROUP BY column
) AS t USING (column)
WHERE t.rank = 1
ORDER BY t.rank DESC
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)
```

[Insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to the rescue!

Basicly this allows you to do any SELECT as normal and then you prepend INSERT INTO and append ON DUPLICATE.

I guess that this query is made up, but what's the point of filtering and ordering the same column?